# Limit number of words in the text box

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am new to Info path, I know how to limit the no.of characters entered in to the text box using string-length function. But is there any way we can limit the number of Words entered in to an multiline text box.

For example a field which is asking to enter 10 words are lesser

Comment: Why don't you go with number of white spaces? If you can count number of white spaces you can easily count the words and go on...

Comment: How do I do that, I tried using string-length(.) - string-length(translate(., " ","")) > 10 given here[link](http://www.hornerit.com/2011/09/limit-number-of-words-in-infopath.html) but that doesnot work

Comment: string-length(field) - string-length(translate(field, " ", "")) should give you the number of white spaces. Try and let me know

Comment: Thanks Naveen string-length(field) - string-length(translate(field, " ", "")) <10 works. The I did was I was tying more than 10 words in the text box thinking it will show ScreenTip while typing. But once i tab from the text box I get the ScreenTip

Comment: But friend, i thought of putting that as answer once it had worked for you so that I would get few points. I was actually waiting for your comments on my suggestion. :) :)

Comment: @Naveen I can remove my answer, you can post it. Just wanted to share the answer.

Comment: I am done, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`string-length(field) - string-length(translate(field, " ", "")) < 10` which is inspired from [KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187667)

> Formula to count the number of occurrences of a single character in
>   one cell If you are concerned about searching for a single character
>   in a single cell, the formula is simplified to:
>   =LEN()-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(,"a",""))

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have received the correct answer from Microsoft Developers Network from Sathiya Kamalanathan. The validation which works is:

string-length(.) - string-length(translate(., " ", "")) > 10

I hope it will help others to solve similar problems.